# How to completely reset|purge certbot state for a set of domains?

Tags: certbot

Let's say I have domain.tld and [www.domain.tld](http://www.domain.tld), and currently there are separate certificates for the main domain and the www subdomain.

- I want to migrate to a setup that uses a single certificate issued for both the domain and the subdomain.
- I want the resulting setup to be squeaky clean, with physically no leftovers from the old setup, no certbot telling me the domains already have certificates when I try to generate the new joint cert, no weird number-suffixed directories created anywhere in certbot's internals, no nothing.
- In short, I want it to be as if I traveled back in time and convinced my past self to do certificates the right way from the beginning.
- ... and it must not reset|interfere with certbot data|state|certificates for other domains.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can simply [delete certificates](https://tecadmin.net/delete-lets-encrypt-certificates-using-certbot/) using `certbot delete`.